# If an ANOVA indicates no main effect and no interaction, should the lack of interaction be stated?

Tags: anova, multiple-comparisons, interpretation

I measured response variable $Y$ at three levels of factor $A$ and four levels of factor $B$, $n=6$ reps/treatment. Results include

- $A$ has strong effects on $Y$.
- $B$ has no effect on $Y$
- There is no $A*B$ interaction

I would like to report all three results (the second two are actually more interesting than the first since all were expected). So far I have:

"The effect of A on Y was significant (ANOVA, $P<0.001$) and $Y$ was different at each level of $A$ (Tukey HSD, $P<0.001$). There was no effect of $B$ on $Y$, and there was no interaction between $A$ and $B.$ This implies that $B$ had no effect on $Y$ **and that the effect of $B$ on $Y$ was similar for all levels of $A$.**"

(Text with bold emphasis is in question)

This approach minimizes the double negative as in "the effect of $B$ on $Y$ was not different at different levels of $A$". Still, neither sounds 'right' to me, thus my post.

In my field, as in many fields of science, non-significant responses are rarely mentioned in the text, and even more rarely are they interpreted, but in this case, previous studies find that $B$ almost always affects $Y$ and the lack of an interaction is notable.

Comment: In papers, when interaction effects aren't significant I still mention in passing that I looked for them to stop reviewers asking about interaction effects. This is obviously different from "accepting H_0" and making a big thing about no effect.

Comment: If your TukeyHSD was not significant at every level would you be reporting it? Would it matter if some levels were and some weren't? In addition to following he advice below consider those questions and what a main effect actually is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, it depends if the interaction was your main hypothesis or not. If this the case, then you are encouraged to report the negative result, otherwise you can simply refit your model (without the B and A:B terms) to get a better estimate of A.

Now, the part of your conclusion that you emphasized doesn't sound correct to me. You can only prove that an observed difference of means is different from 0 (or any other fixed value, according to your alternative hypothesis), you cannot "accept" the null. If your test is non-significant, it simply means that you cannot reject $H_0$. Non-significant results can also reflect lack of power (Type II error).

Also, rather than simply reporting crude p-values, it would be better (and it actually follows the [APA](http://apastyle.apa.org/) recommendations) to also report some kind of effect size or difference of means, together with your inferential results.

Here is an example for reporting results from a factorial ANOVA (it has to be rework to fit your specific experimental design since your factors have a lot of levels):

A two-way analysis of variance yielded a main effect for A factor, $F(\nu_1,\nu_2) = 0.00$, $p < .05$, such that the average "value" was significantly higher in the $a_1$ condition (Mean=0.00, SD=0.00) compared to $a_2$ (Mean=0.00, SD=0.00) and $a_3$ (Mean=0.00, SD=0.00, Tukey HSD, all p<0.05). The main effect of B was non-significant ($F(\nu_1,\nu_2) = 0.00$, $p = 0.00$), and no interaction effect was found significant ($F(\nu_1,\nu_2) = 0.00$, $p = 0.00$) indicating that the effect of A on Y was not significantly different across the B levels.

Comment: I am sorry chl, I think we were almost answering this question together at the same time. Basically, you and me are pointing to the same fact.

Comment: @chi The effect of A was expected, while the effects of B and A*B were both main hypotheses. And I am going to show the effect sizes in a figure. Thank you for reminding me not to make the error of accepting Ho.

Answer (score 6):

Please let me know if you have replicates in your experiment. As you mention using Tukey HSD, I am guessing you don't have any replicates. If you experiment analyzes test of additivity in a two-way factorial Analysis of Variance (ANOVA) with one observation per cell, then please read ahead or otherwise ignore my solution.

Assuming I am thinking in the right direction, it may be possible that **B affects A, but it doesn't affect Y in form of a multiplicative term like A*B**. In general, B can *affect*  *Y* in even if the interaction *A* * *B* is not significant.

The reason for this is the assumption of special form of relation between A and B (ie A*B) that affects Y in Tukey HSD Test. Please see the wikipedia article about [Tukey HSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tukey%27s_test_of_additivity) for further details.

I am sorry if this was not the test that you were conducting.

But even if the interaction is not statistically significant, it doesn't imply that B doesn't affect Y. Even if this is a randomized experiment and you are allowed to relate significance and causation, but **not able to reject the null hypothesis $H_o$ (ie p-value is $\geq \alpha$ ) doesn't mean that you accept $H_o$**.

Please accept my apologies, if I completely misunderstood you.

---

**Update after David's details**

A few common themes that should be addressed first:

1. If you expect interaction in your main effects here *A and B*, then testing for the significance of main effects doesn't make sense. (cf. an elegant paper by Dr. Venables [first link](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&&sa=X&ei=BSK0TJfsJ9DWngekmaDGDA&sqi=2&ved=0CCEQBSgA&q=venable+S+plus+conference+washington+exegeses&spell=1&emsg=NCSR&noj=1&ei=BSK0TJfsJ9DWngekmaDGDA) )
2. I think doing sub-sampling doesn't help you (when I say *help*, I mean in the context of the number degrees of the freedom of F distribution which is used to test is *treatment effect* = 0). By sub-sampling, I mean replication at Block by Treatment level. In RCB, the degrees of freedom wasted in replication can only be used to test if the block effect is present or not. Using Blocks in expt. design is a "trick" to control for the extra variation which is not the main interest. In your case variance because of *trays* (block) is not of importance, so I don't know if it is useful to waste extra resources (ie money) in testing if the variance due to trays is significant or not.
3. I would be afraid to come to the conclusion that there was no block effect. The block effect in your case is random, and the test uses some "strong assumptions" to determine the sampling distribution (which may or may not be true depending on the strong assumptions). If your experiment started with RCB, please retain the structure of the data. *Pooling of samples from block may confound your conclusions*. You are again committing the error of accepting $H_o$ if you say there is no *block effect* (I am assuming you conclude no block effect by testing hypotheses. right?).
4. The point 4. further stresses my point 3. of choosing *not to subsample*, as essentially subsampling lets you test something (trays effect) which is not of primary interest to you. Even if this was of interest, you invest your money in replication to test something whose sampling distribution is not appropriately determined.
5. In the comment you say 12 treatments, but you only mention *A* and *B* as your treatment variables. Did you mean 12 levels for treatments *A* and *B* respectively? If yes, then you have only 2 treatments with 12 levels. If no, then you need to change the model.

For further details about subsampling in RCB, refer to chapter 3 of George Casella's [design book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387759646).

Sincere apologies again, if I misunderstood you.

Comment: Hi @suncoolsu, there are n=6 replicates in each of the 12 treatments. It was set up as an RCBD with three blocks with n=2 reps/treatment/block because there were three trays with for 24 samples each, but there was no block effect so I dropped it from my analysis. Sorry for the omission

Comment: Hello @David, I will be a little uncomfortable with saying - "there was no block effect". Please see my updated reply for your answer.

Comment: Hi @suncoolsu, Thank you again for your response. re: 1. This is an interesting point, I will look at Venable's reference. re: 2. The blocking and replication within blocks was based on the fact that the trays held 24 samples, so I blocked them in case there was any effect of tray positon or time of measurement. re: 3. Thanks for again for reminding me not to incorrectly interpret my findings, e.g. by saying that there was no block effect. It is a bad habit. re: 5. I should have clarified that by 12 treatments, I meant the 12 permutations of three levels of A and four of B.

Comment: Hello @David, I understand your point of blocking on trays to remove the variation because of them. This is perfectly justified and you should block if you can. But what I am trying to point out is: as you said, there are 2 replicates for a particular block and treatment level (say: tray 1 had two replicates of first level for trt A) IMHO is _not correct_. If you really want to block for positions as well, probably a more efficient design like **latin square** or **split plot** designs may be the way to go. The choice of specific design depends on your resources, your parameter of intrst. etc.

Comment: Hi @suncoolsu. Your points are good but, as the experiment is complete, the design is fixed.

Comment: Re the first point (1) - I read Venables' article that you referenced about main effects being an artifact of experimental design (the levels chosen of each factor) when interactions are present (p. 13), but I believe my study is one of the 'rare and special' exceptions, because the main effect of A on Y is very large, i.e., Y is an order of magnitude different at each level of A, while any effect of B would have been on the order of a 10-50% change or so; of course the point is moot since the interaction effect was not significant.

Comment: "Three solid gold (significance) stars on the main effects will do very nicely, thank you, and if there are a few little stars here and there on the interactions, so much the better!" -Venables 2000 [N.B. said in jest, but this attitude is so pervasive in research, peer review, and graduate training is so great I thought it would be edifying to include it here.